# CAPE_CIN returning incorrect values

Tags: python, metpy

I'm interested in calculating CAPE from past soundings. I've done some test calculations and for some reason my CAPE values are not agreeing with those that are provided along with current soundings.

e.g., see the [latest sounding from Boa Vista, Brazil](http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2021&MONTH=01&FROM=3112&TO=3112&STNM=82022) (randomly picked b/c warm enough to have an appreciable CAPE in January). The data show a CAPE of 189 J/kg, whereas metpy is giving me much lower values. Specifically, if I use all of the data for all pressure levels in the sounding, I get 72 J/kg. If instead I just use standard pressure levels (1000, 925, etc. -- shown in the code below), I get 1 J/kg.

I've copied my code below. Could someone help me figure out how to do this correctly?

Thanks,
Guillaume

```
# IMPORT:
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import numpy as np

# SOUNDING:
p=np.array([1003,925,850,700,500,400,300,200,100])
t=np.array([24.4,20.6,16.4,10.4,-5.3,-15.5,-28.7,-52.3,-79.7])
d=np.array([21.1,20.2,16.3,6.5,-7.0,-25.5,-51.7,-73.3,-87.7])

# UNITS:
p = units.Quantity(p, "hPa")
t = units.Quantity(t, "degC")
d = units.Quantity(d, "degC")

# CALCULATE CAPE:
cape1,cin1 = mpcalc.surface_based_cape_cin(p,t,d)
prof = mpcalc.parcel_profile(p, t[0], d[0])

cape2,cin2 = mpcalc.cape_cin(p,t,d,prof)

print(cape1)
print(cape2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The calculated values from the Wyoming archive use an average of the [lowest 500m](http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/indices.html) to represent the parcel for their calculations. While unfortunately not trivial, it is possible to do this with MetPy:

```
from datetime import datetime

import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays, units
import numpy as np
from siphon.simplewebservice.wyoming import WyomingUpperAir

df = WyomingUpperAir.request_data(datetime(2021, 1, 31, 12), '82022')
data = pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays(df)

# Calculate the mixed parcel--need to pass pressure as an additional variable to "mix" so that we get
# an appropriate "average pressure" to use as the mixed parcel
parcel_temp, parcel_dewp, mixed_press = mpcalc.mixed_layer(data['pressure'], data['temperature'],
                                                           data['dewpoint'], data['pressure'],
                                                           height=data['height'], depth=500 * units.m)

# Replace the lowest part of the sounding with the mixed value
press_mixed = np.concatenate([np.atleast_1d(mixed_press), data['pressure'][data['pressure'] < mixed_press]])
temp_mixed = np.concatenate([np.atleast_1d(parcel_temp), data['temperature'][data['pressure'] < mixed_press]])
dewpt_mixed = np.concatenate([np.atleast_1d(parcel_dewp), data['dewpoint'][data['pressure'] < mixed_press]])

# Calculate the parcel profile, including the LCL--this interpolates the sounding to the level of the LCL
# as well, so that the profile and all variables have the same points
p, t, d, prof = mpcalc.parcel_profile_with_lcl(press_mixed, temp_mixed, dewpt_mixed)

lcl_press, lcl_temp = mpcalc.lcl(mixed_press, parcel_temp, parcel_dewp)
cape, cin = mpcalc.cape_cin(p, t, d, prof)
```

With the mixing in place, I get LCL pressure/temp values (943.84 hPa and 20.52 degC) that agree well with Wyoming. This gives me CAPE of 208 J/kg and CIN of -16 J/kg, which are in better agreement with those reported by Wyoming. Any differences, especially for this marginally unstable sounding can be due to differences in the detail of the calculation, just like the original difference was caused by using a shallow mixed parcel.

This should be do-able with `metpy.calc.mixed_layer_cape_cin`, but that currently does not work with non-pressure-based depths due to [a bug](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1718).